# How to resolve some issues about Unhandled exception. Error while validating the service descriptor. Unhandled exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have an ASP.NET Core mvc Project using .net6. When I run my project in Visual Studio in the Output I got Unhandled exception.

I got a class AutoMapperConfig:

```
public static class AutoMapperConfig
{
private static bool initialized;

        public static IMapper MapperInstance { get; set; }
    
        public static void RegisterMappings(params Assembly[] assemblies)
        {
            if (initialized)
            {
                return;
            }
    
            initialized = true;
    
            var types = assemblies.SelectMany(a => a.GetExportedTypes()).ToList();
    
            var config = new MapperConfigurationExpression();
            config.CreateProfile(
                "ReflectionProfile",
                configuration =>
                {
                    // IMapFrom<>
                    foreach (var map in GetFromMaps(types))
                    {
                        configuration.CreateMap(map.Source, map.Destination);
                    }
    
                    // IMapTo<>
                    foreach (var map in GetToMaps(types))
                    {
                        configuration.CreateMap(map.Source, map.Destination);
                    }
    
                    // IHaveCustomMappings
                    foreach (var map in GetCustomMappings(types))
                    {
                        map.CreateMappings(configuration);
                    }
                });
            MapperInstance = new Mapper(new MapperConfiguration(config));
        }
    
        private static IEnumerable<TypesMap> GetFromMaps(IEnumerable<Type> types)
        {
            var fromMaps = from t in types
                           from i in t.GetTypeInfo().GetInterfaces()
                           where i.GetTypeInfo().IsGenericType &&
                                 i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IMapFrom<>) &&
                                 !t.GetTypeInfo().IsAbstract &&
                                 !t.GetTypeInfo().IsInterface
                           select new TypesMap
                           {
                               Source = i.GetTypeInfo().GetGenericArguments()[0],
                               Destination = t,
                           };
    
            return fromMaps;
        }
    
        private static IEnumerable<TypesMap> GetToMaps(IEnumerable<Type> types)
        {
            var toMaps = from t in types
                         from i in t.GetTypeInfo().GetInterfaces()
                         where i.GetTypeInfo().IsGenericType &&
                               i.GetTypeInfo().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IMapTo<>) &&
                               !t.GetTypeInfo().IsAbstract &&
                               !t.GetTypeInfo().IsInterface
                         select new TypesMap
                         {
                             Source = t,
                             Destination = i.GetTypeInfo().GetGenericArguments()[0],
                         };
    
            return toMaps;
        }
    
        private static IEnumerable<IHaveCustomMappings> GetCustomMappings(IEnumerable<Type> types)
        {
            var customMaps = from t in types
                             from i in t.GetTypeInfo().GetInterfaces()
                             where typeof(IHaveCustomMappings).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(t) &&
                                   !t.GetTypeInfo().IsAbstract &&
                                   !t.GetTypeInfo().IsInterface
                             select (IHaveCustomMappings)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    
            return customMaps;
        }
    
        private class TypesMap
        {
            public Type Source { get; set; }
    
            public Type Destination { get; set; }
        }
    }

}
```

I got an interface class IHaveCustomMappings with a method to Map my models

```
public interface IHaveCustomMappings     
{                                                     
     void CreateMappings(IProfileExpression configuration);     
}
```

My BlogPostViewModel inherited IMapFrom<BlogPost>, IHaveCustomMappings where I had implemented the method CreateMappings.

```
public void CreateMappings(IProfileExpression configuration)         
{             
configuration.CreateMap<BlogPost, BlogPostViewModel>()
.ForMember(b => b.Date, opt => opt.MapFrom(b => b.CreatedOn))
.ForMember(b => b.Author, opt => opt.MapFrom(b => b.Author))
.ForMember(b => b.UrlImage, opt => opt.MapFrom(b => b.UrlImage))
.ForMember(b => b.UserReaction, opt => opt.MapFrom(b => b.UserReaction));
}
```

My Application Service are

```
            services.AddScoped<IDbQueryRunner, DbQueryRunner>();
            services.AddScoped<IAppRepository, AppRepository>();

            services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
            services.AddScoped<IEventService, EventService>();
            services.AddScoped<IBlogPostService, BlogPostService>();
            services.AddScoped<IShoppingCartService, ShoppingCartService>();
            services.AddScoped<IArtOrderService, ArtOrderService>();
            services.AddScoped<ISettingsService, SettingsService>();
            services.AddScoped<ICommentsService, CommentsService>();
            services.AddScoped<IArtStoreService, ArtStoreService>();
            services.AddScoped<IEventOrderService, EventOrderService>();
            services.AddScoped<ICloudinaryService, CloudinaryService>();
```

I got Unhandled exception

> Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: ArtGallery.Services.Data.Contracts.IBlogPostService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: ArtGallery.Services.Data.BlogPostService': Unable to resolve service for type 'AutoMapper.IConfigurationProvider' while attempting to activate 'ArtGallery.Services.Data.BlogPostService'.)
> System.InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: ArtGallery.Services.Data.Contracts.IBlogPostService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: ArtGallery.Services.Data.BlogPostService': Unable to resolve service for type 'AutoMapper.IConfigurationProvider' while attempting to activate 'ArtGallery.Services.Data.BlogPostService'.
> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'AutoMapper.IConfigurationProvider' while attempting to activate 'ArtGallery.Services.Data.BlogPostService'.

I am trying to map my model with a class method CreateMappings that I had shared above in this post.

I am not sure how I have to map the properties, because it look like the implementation for CreateMappings doesn't work. I am still Unable to resolve service for type 'AutoMapper.IConfigurationProvider'.
In the Program.cs of Web layer where I am registering my services I have tried AddSingleton, but my project it is not starting. When I am using AddScoped the project is starting but I got the same error mentioned above.

Also I tried to registered only my BlogPostService in Program.cs with
`services.AddSingleton<IBlogPostService, BlogPostService>();`
Project doesn't starts again. What can I try next?

Comment: Can you show BlogPostService.cs

Comment: Here it is a link to BlogPostService.cs  https://pastebin.com/ExsBRC0d